# Incremental publish to JBoss does not update JSP files, only Java files.

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jboss, publish

I feel like I'm having this issue: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-264

I am using Eclipse Indigo, with the latest JBossAS Tools. The target is JBoss 4.2. When I make a change to a JSP file, it is automatically published to the server - but the changes don't appear unless I do a "Full Publish" of my application.

Any reason this would be happening?

Answer (score 0):

You should just reopen the issue.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but I feel that the issue is on my end.